# Assign IDs to Elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to  assign unique ids to paragraphs in a HTML file.
How do i do this using loops in a JavaScript?
(assuming that I know the number of paragraphs in it)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function count() {
            var num = $("p").size();
            for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                $ "p".innerhtml();
                $id = i;
                I dont know
                if this is right.is this how we assign ids ?
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Count paragraphs</h1>
    <div>
        <p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
        <p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
        <p>This is paragraph 3.</p>
        <p>This is paragraph 4.</p>
    </div>
    <form action="">
        <input type="button" value="count" onclick="count()"></input>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function count() {
        var par = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        for (var i=0,j=par.length;i<j;i++) {
            par[i].setAttribute('id',i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/paladu/7/edit?html,css,js,output)***

**JavaScript**

```
var elP = document.querySelectorAll("p");  
[].slice.call(elP).forEach(function(el, v) {
    el.id = el.id || "p"+v;    // or use `el.id = "p"+v;` to overwrite
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$("p").prop("id", function(idx, currID) {
    return currID || "p"+idx; // or use `return "p"+idx;` to overwrite
});
```

The above uses the `idx, currID` (index, value) arguments of the `.prop()` method callback
and it will assign an ID `pN` (N starting from `0`) to all your `<p>` without overwriting an existing ID.

Before:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p id="foo"></p>
<p></p>
```

After:

```
<p id="p0"></p>
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="foo"></p>
<p id="p3"></p>
```

P.S: `</input>` is an illegal closing tag. <sup>([See: **Void elements**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-elements))</sup>

Comment: clean and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) methods together like:

```
function count() {
        $('p').each(function(index){
           if($(this).prop('id') === ""){ // make sure that we're not overwriting any already assigned id
               $(this).prop('id', 'para-'+index); // index starts at 0
           }
        });
}
```

Valid id's cannot be just numbers, so i have prefixed them with the phrase "para-"

Comment: You should know that `typeof $(this).prop('id')` will return `"string"` having your element an ID or not. Don't use jQuery where you don't need to. jQuery *is* JS so knw your properties and use `this.id`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan we only want to add an id when there isnt one. if theres no id it returns "undefined". totally agreed about only jquery when needed. The question appeared to be asking how to do it using jquery however :)

Comment: @haxxxton can you please post an example where an element *that has no ID* will return `typeof $(this).prop('id') == "undefined"` >> `true`? Also you can find some nice suggestions about a good use of [DOM properties here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan my bad, i had been using `.attr('id')` in my testing, and then changed to `.prop('id')` later without checking that it was different. You are correct. it is `.attr('id')` that returns "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function count() {
    $('p').each(function(index) {
        this.id = 'p' + index;
    });
}
```

This will basically cycle through all the 'p' elements.  In the context of the function given to the each function, this represents the HtmlElement.  You can assign the id directly.  There is no need to wrap the HtmlElement in a jQuery object since the id can be accessed on the raw element.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3u15hvw/)  (You will have to inspect the Html in the result to see the ids)

Comment: But it would still create duplicate IDs if the `<p>` elements had separate parents wouldn't it?

Comment: I tried adding a <p> with under a separate parent and it didn't assign duplicate ids unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying

Comment: @thePav No, cause the index `i` argument represents the index inside the returned jQuery *each* collection. Though the `.each()` iterator is not needed at all cause `$('p')` is already a collection of elements so you can go immediately for `.prop()`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
    count = function() {
            $('div > p').each(function(index, el){
            el.id = 'para-'+index;
            });
    };
```

The > is used for direct child. You don't have to worry about a p inside a p becaue it's illegal.

http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/ywadbga0/1/

Comment: Would this not create duplicate IDs if the `<p>` elements had separate parents? Also, not to forget - IDs can not start with a number.

Comment: Well it's specific for his code... he'll get the point. One can always use `'div > p'`. Agreed about the name

Comment: p inside a p is invalid anyway ;)

Comment: Don't make functions valuable global unless you want real issues in the future.

Comment: @miro, I meant more if it were `<div><p><p></div><div><p></div>` - But don't worry, @RokoC.Buljan explained it in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914671/assign-ids-to-paragraphs-in-html-using-javascript/27914742?noredirect=1#comment44228762_27914742

Answer (score -1):

I didnt get if you want innerHTML or id attribute, but i'll do it in both ways.

HTML

```
<h1>Count paragraphs</h1>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<button onclick='countParagraphs()'>Count it!</button>
```

Javascript ( with Jquery )

```
function countParagraphs() {
    var count = 0;
    $("p").each( function() {
        count ++;
        $(this).html( "This is paragraph " + count ).attr( "id", count );
    });
}
```